# How to shift this image to the left?

Tags: graphics

As you can see in the picture below, the diagram is shifted to the left. The code I am using to display this image is give below:

```
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{"Law 2".png}
\end{center}
```

The name of the image file is "Law 2".  How should I go about fixing this problem? I've also read answers to a related question, but, since I am a beginner in Latex, it's difficult for me to understand their logic. So, an ideal answer would be one that strictly deals with my case.
[image]

**Update [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0PaR.png)**

After trying `\fbox{\includegraphics{"Law 2".png}}` I got, the following:

[image]

**Update [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmAbQ.png)**

After trying `\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{"Law 2".png}}` I got the following picture:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps, there's a lot of white space on the left boundary of the image? If this is the case, the `center` environment will use this white space too in order to provide the 'correct` filling. Use `\fbox{\includegraphics{...}}` and you will see the amount of white space.

Comment: Probably, the bounding box of the graphics file is wider than what  see. To check this point,, use `\fbox{\includegraphics{Law_2.png}` (note I replaced the blank space in the file name with an underscore).

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, I did as you suggested. What should I do now?

Comment: What happens if you try `\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{"Law 2".png}}`? Looks like much of the white space is part of the image, so maybe cropping it (either with an external program or latex) might help.

Comment: Do `\includegraphics[trim=20 0 0 0,width=\textwidth]{Law2.png}` (avoid spaces in file names, but the trick with quotes can work). Experiment with various values instead of 20 until you get a satisfying output (keep `\fbox` during the attempts). Or clip the image with some specialized software.

Comment: Offtopic: but are you sure that the image should not have a caption?

Comment: @ShreyAryan: See the other comments, they were apparently better than mine

Comment: @egreg What does the value "20" represent? Am I supposed to increase it or decrease it? Can I make it negative? And what about the zeroes after "20"? Are they of any relevance to solving my problem?

Comment: @egreg Your technique worked! Thank you so much...